# SetPixel and GetPixel give different values C#

Tags: c#, bitmap, pixel, dispose

I have 2 different classes. I am setting and saving (with `Bitmap.Save()`) a bitmap from an image in a class. I am getting pixel from this `Bitmap` in another class. But I get very different values from the values I set. I randomly gave the numbers below to explain my problem more clearly.

The class where I use the `SetPixel` method:

```
bmp.SetPixel(indisX, indisY, Color.FromArgb(shift, shiftX, shiftY)); 
//index x=0, indexY=0, shift=5, shiftX=7, shiftY=10
```

The class where I use the SetPixel method:

```
//indexX=0, indexY=0
pixel = bmp.GetPixel(indisX, indisY);
//pixel.R=23, pixel.G=55, pixel.B=30
```

I called the image as Bmp in both methods with the following code:

```cs
using (OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    dlg.Filter = "jpg files (*.jpg)|*.jpg";
    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        bmp = new Bitmap(dlg.FileName);
        textBox2.Text = dlg.FileName;
    }
}
```

By the way, when I get the image with the following code, there is no problem. Everything works fine. But this has other problems for me. So I have to use the above code:

```cs
using (OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    dlg.Filter = "jpg files (*.jpg)|*.jpg";
    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(dlg.FileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            img = Image.FromStream(fs);
            fs.Close();
        }
        bmp = new Bitmap(img);
    }
}
```

Comment: JPEG files use a lossy compression. I.e. shap edges get wavy. Use PNG instead.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes but why FileStream works fine.

Comment: By the way, the stream needs to remain open as long as the Bitmap object exists; it's in the specs. That's why `FileStream` gives issues; you close the stream right away, before you clone it with `bmp = new Bitmap(img)`. You should put that line just after `Image.FromStream`, inside the using block.

Comment: For the record, the `fs.Close()` is pointless; the _whole purpose_ of the `using` block is to automatically close and clean up the used resources at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Like Olivier wrote in the comment, common JPEG is a lossy format. When you save an image as JPEG, it will still look similar to the original, but individual pixel values might change.

This is the same whether you load the JPEG directly from file or using a stream, as shown by the following stand-alone test code:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(100, 100, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
Color testColor = Color.FromArgb(23, 55, 30);
bmp.SetPixel(0, 0, testColor);
var readColor = bmp.GetPixel(0, 0);
string message = "Before saving, Colors equal: " + (testColor == readColor).ToString();
string filename = @"d:\temp\tempimage";
// Save lossy JPEG then lossless PNG
bmp.Save(filename + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
bmp.Save(filename + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
// Load JPEG
bmp = new Bitmap(filename + ".jpg");
readColor = bmp.GetPixel(0, 0);
message += "\nJPEG Colors equal: " + (testColor == readColor).ToString();
// Load PNG
bmp = new Bitmap(filename + ".png");
readColor = bmp.GetPixel(0, 0);
message += "\nPNG Colors equal: " + (testColor == readColor).ToString();
Image img = null;
// Load JPEG using stream
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename + ".jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
   img = Image.FromStream(fs);
   fs.Close();
}
bmp = new Bitmap(img);
readColor = bmp.GetPixel(0, 0);
message += "\nStream JPEG Colors equal: " + (testColor == readColor).ToString();
// Load PNG using stream
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename + ".png", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
   img = Image.FromStream(fs);
   fs.Close();
}
bmp = new Bitmap(img);
readColor = bmp.GetPixel(0, 0);
message += "\nStream PNG Colors equal: " + (testColor == readColor).ToString();
MessageBox.Show(message);
```

The result I got from this code is:

```
Before saving, Colors equal: True
JPEG Colors equal: False
PNG Colors equal: True
Stream JPEG Colors equal: False
Stream PNG Colors equal: True
```

Try this code and see what's different in your code that's causing file loading to be different from stream loading.

There is a JPEG variation called **lossless JPEG** that does not cause color changes. Many common JPEG loading and saving functions and applications do not support this variation, but if you need it, it's supported in professional imaging libraries such as the LEADTOOLS Imaging SDK (Disclosure: I work for its vendor). If you'd to try it, you can download a free evaluation edition [here](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads).

Comment: Thank you so much, my friend. I had already given up on using JPEG. I am using PNG.